# WPF - DataGrid - Exclusão

Tags: c#, wpf

Como eu posso pegar o índice de um item selecionado no meu DataGrid em WPF?

Eu sei que no WEB Forms eu consigo pegar assim:

```
MainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta isso.

```
foreach (var item in MainGrid.SelectedItems)
{
     this.SelectedProducts.Add((B.Product)item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se eu não entendi errado...

```
MainGrid.SelectedIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer pegar o valor de um item selecionado e armazenar em um atributo, tente assim...exemplo:

```
Usuario u = new Usuario();
u = DataGrid.SelectedItem as Usuario;
string nome = u.nome;
```